# fading container, but not the popup

Tags: jquery, html, css

can you fade the background of a container, but not the pop-up form contained within it?

I have seen a few out there, but its all separate.

This is what I mean.

```
    <div class='wrapper'>
        <div class='popUp'>
            <!-- CODE HERE -->
        </div>
    </div>
```

with something along the line of.

```
    $('.wrapper').fadeTo( "slow" , 0.5);
    $(".popUp").fadeIn(450);
    $('.popUp').fadeTo( "slow" , 1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to make this work is to make a second `div` inside of the wrapper that is your background.

```
<div class='wrapper'>
     <div class='background'></div>
     <div class='popUp'>
          <!-- CODE HERE -->
     </div>
</div>
```

And style the `.background` class to take up the entire size of the wrapper.

Comment: Thanks, I take no credit as I stole this from other people a long time ago.